# Displaying ImageView edges as arcs

Tags: android, imageview, geometric-arc

I want to display the the images by using the ImageView with edges as arc

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try here: [How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners)